# .NET runtime/sdk installation on Debian production server

Tags: debian, dotnet-framework, fhs

I have dedicated Debian container on Proxmox to run ASP.NET Web API application. It requires .NET runtime (or SDK that contains runtime), like Java.

I have no problem to make it work, but I'm struggling with installation for the **production environment**.

By default, the current version of .NET installer script installs it in... user home directory (`/home/myusername/dotnet` for example). I don't like this for few reasons. For example - I don't want to share my personal account with other people who will manage this server/container in my organization.

The question is: **How to do it properly?**

1. Is it good idea to install .NET Core in more "normal" place for linux software? By "normal" I mean something like `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` or other location in accordance with the conventions described by the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)?).
2. Should I create dedicated system user like "dotnet" or "www" and run daemon by this user? The Apache installer creates the "www" system user if I'm not mistaken.

- if so, how should I set up permissions/group for this user? I don't know if regular linux user can run application that needs to open TCP socket

3. Should I think about anything else?

Please note that I have added `dotnet-framework` tag to this question, because there is no `dotnet` and I can't add it. For people who don't work in this environment: .NET Framework (Windows) and .NET Core (multi-platform) have been merged into just .NET (multi-platform).